# FactoryGirl with Oracle enhanced adapter - an attribute of name 'id' is not assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, activerecord, factory-bot

I have an Oracle test table with ID column that is *not* a primary key, *not* an autoincrement and with *no* sequence defined. It only has `NOT NULL` defined. The corresponding structure in development schema is an Oracle View rather than a table with a primary key defined against the ID column.

My factory definition looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    id 'abc'
  end
end
```

These tests fails

```
test "should build model 1" do
  w = FactoryGirl.build(:model)
  assert_not_nil w.id #fails - id is always nil
end

test "should build model 2" do
  w = FactoryGirl.build(:model, :id => 'abc')
  assert_not_nil w.id #fails - id is always nil
end
```

I've added `attr_accessible :id` to my model (just in case), but with no luck.

I've also defined `id=` method in my model `def id= id; @id = id; end`. The call is made to the method and @id is written, but looks like it is overwritten later in the callstack (between FactoryGirl and ActiveRecord).

Other attributes are normally assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit:

The `write` method in `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write` module has the line `attr_name = self.class.primary_key if attr_name == 'id'`

It means that if the attribute name to be set has the name of 'id', pick the primary_key as the name of the attribute to assign the new value to. And since in my test table there is no primary_key returned by the oracle_enhanced_adapter (rightfully), the whole write operation is skipped.

My solution was to override the `write` method skipping that line so that the id is written to.

Answer (score 0):

What if you explicitly set the primary key? With set_primary_key nil

Just a thought; hopefully allows you to not need to override the write method.